# Psexec and perl script with multiple arguements

Tags: psexec

I 'm trying to remotely execute a perl script that needs to run with some arguments/switches, but I 'm failing miserably :p What I 'm currently doing is:

```
psexec \\computer -u my_username "path\to\perl" "path\to\perl_script" --switch1 --switch2
```

This fails. I 've tried the above with a couple of ways, playing with the quotes, but didn't manage so far. Any ideas?

Comment: are switch1 and 2 switches for perl, or the script itself? are there any spaces in either of the paths your passing in? also you need to use \\computer, instead of \computer. its a UNC path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the user a domain user or a local user of the remote computer "computer"?

This works for me with my windows domain credentials as a practical example:

```
psexec \\server01 -u mydomain\megamorf cmd /c "\\share\Software\Prezi\PreziDesktop4.2.1.exe /S /v/qb"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The user is a domain user. Also, the switches I referred in my original post are for the perl script itself, not perl. I think I didn't clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to do my job like this:

`psexec \\computer -u my_username -w "working\path" cmd /c "script"`

Cheers! :)